# Create a template for iPhone projects in XCode?

Tags: xcode, templates, projects, xcode-template

How do I create another project template in **XCode**? I want to make another one which will include all of my libraries and have the correct headers and frameworks added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this ars technica post](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/04/cocoa-dev-design-your-own-xcode-project-templates.ars). The general idea is that you set up a project the way you like, then copy it into Xcode's templates folder in `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/`.